# Equation of state for liquid metals (CFD Application)

Tags: fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations, metals

I am currently looking for the Equation of state used for metals (fluid state) for CFD Application on metallurgy.

Do you know a book where I can find them?

Comment: You're talking about a P-V-T equation of state? Over what pressure and temperature range? Don't know of anything specifically intended for liquid metals, but there are commonly used high-pressure equations of state.

Comment: @SamuelWeir Yes P-V-T. Specifically the temperature range used in metallurgy industry.

Comment: And what sorts of pressures? A few atmospheres of pressure? More?

Comment: @SamuelWeir low and high (all possible range because i want to improve the CFD for metallurgy). If you can give the best reference, i'll be able to figure out the needs. Thanks you for your assistance

Comment: Look up the Birch-Murnaghan ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birch–Murnaghan_equation_of_state ) and Vinet (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose–Vinet_equation_of_state ) equations of state. They are commonly used for fitting high-pressure data. If you're working at moderate temperatures, you can also just add in a linear or quadratic temperature term to them.

Comment: @SamuelWeir Ok Great. I'll do my own research then understand how to use them. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Liquid metal is baseically a very viscous fluid with very high density, thus the equations of state for a liquid can be applied as long as you consider the mass, density and right viscosity of that. 
This you can find in any thermodynamics textbook, I do suggest the Fundamentals of Thermodynamics by by Richard E. Sonntag, Claus Borgnakke, Gordon J. Van Wylen.